# How to see total unique users on FB Analytics?

Tags: firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am struggling to navigate Firebase Analytics and would greatly appreciate any assistance or direction to relevant documentation.

My goal is to leverage Firebase Analytics or Google Analytics 4 (GA4) to monitor the following metrics:

1. Total unique users (number of users who have created an account).
2. Segmented total unique users (number of unique users for specific titles such as bronze, silver, etc.).

I'm unsure if it's possible to view the total number of users to **date**, rather than just on a weekly or monthly basis. Being able to see total users to date is my main goal! I apologize for any confusion and appreciate your help in clarifying this matter. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.